# TF31003-Either u have not entered proper credentials or

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

The issue is pretty straight forward, am able to connect to my TFS from my remote machine(our DEV box) and unable to connect from local PC. I was able to connect from my local PC till yesterday and don't know whats wrong ...
Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Likey this is cached credentials. Look in the control panel for the "credential manager" and delete or change the saved credentials for TFS.

Comment: And i checked the following links as well0but sadly no luck:(--https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e8fb58cf-35fb-4653-8d00-93f51e7cda31/troubleshooting-connections-from-internet-explorer-visual-studio-to-visual-studio-online?forum=TFService

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded the IE version and rebooted the machine. That's it! Problem solved!!